# Change route with or without login in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, routes, root

Like the title says, i would like to change the route depending on if there is a user logged in or not, similarly to facebook. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't change the route, you just add a `:before_filter` in your controller.  There's a few ways to do it, but a simple example is pretend your root points at `homeController#main`.  On top of the controller you have something like

```
before_filter :check_login, :only => {:main}
```

And then in your ApplicationController you write a method like

```
def check_login
    if !session[:userid].nil
        redirect_to :controller => :users, :action => :profile
    end
end
```

Which will check your session variable for a user and redirect to their profile if it exists, if not, then it will render your main method normally.

More information and examples [here](http://www.fortytwo.gr/blog/6/Rails-Power-to-the-filters).

Comment: Is there a way to actually make the path '/' change what is rendered? Or only redirect upon going there?